# Xcode Organizer error. High RES Icons for Mac App 1024x1024 can not be validated

Tags: icons, osx-lion

Xcode 4.5
 Mountain Lion

Method : letting Xcode automatically create ICNS format from an iconset folder

When I validate in Organizer for the Mac App Store, I get the error:
 The Application bundle does not contain an icon in ICNS format, containing both a 512x512 and a 512x512@2x image.

Both icon files are contained in the HM_MAC.iconset folder.
 Both icons are produce in PhotoShop using Export for Web Device option. Both
 are exported from a photo shop image that has 1024x1024 pixels.

I notice that in the file Info windows for the two icons, under 'More Info'
 just after creation it shows:

```
Dimensions: 1024 x 1024 and 512 x 512
```

Then later, when I check the same info I see
that the

```
Dimension area for the larger 1024 x 1024 icon is BLANK.
```

Image showing file info for icons:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/79640605@N04/8281909148/in/photostream/>

In Xcode, after adding the iconset folder to the project, if I click
on the iconset folder, the icon appears with a slider beneath. If 
I slide the slider, the maximum size displayed at the lower right is 512.

To restate the problem. I have 10 PNG files that I need to put into an 'iconset' file

All ten files share:
  RGB with no Alpha
  all produced by PhotoShop CS4 which shows the size: 1024:1024 for source file.

The two largest of my ten files are :

icon_512x512.png
icon_512x512@2x.png // necessary for MBP Retina screen

Finder's GetInfo View can display the dimensions of all these PNG files
except the largest, i.e., icon_512x512@2x.png

If I open this largest file in iPhoto, iPhoto can display the dimensions
correctly, namely, 1024 x 1024 and size 280 kB

What is causing Finder to fail to calculate the file size? Whatever it is,
the same thing is perhaps causing myApp to fail validation in Organizer.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently 10 icon files from 16x16 to 1024x1024 required for an OS X app.

```
For example icon_16x16.png .
```

I created an iconset file/folder with these 10 PNG files.
I then dragged the file, myApp.iconset to the Resources group folder of the Xcode project.
When I clicked on the iconset, the icon appeared in Xcode with a slider bar beneath. 
As I slid the slider, the size displayed changed from 16 to 512. 1024 was no where to be seen.
When I archived the project in order to distribute to Mac Store, I got an validation error
indicating I did not have both  512x512@2x and 512x512 files.

Xcode is now supposed to automatically create an ICNS file from an iconset at build time.
It did not seem to work on my iconset.

Then I took the same ten PNG files and created an ICNS file from them. In terminal I used  iconutil .

```
See : man iconutil
```

It created an ICNS format package named myApp.icns which I put in Resources/ folder. Then set CFBundleIconFile to 'myApp.icns'  in

```
Target -> Build Settings
```

Everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

"The Application bundle does not contain an icon in ICNS format, containing both a 512x512 and a 512x512@2x image."

When working on a free-version, I renamed `<string>` for "CFBundleIconFile" entry and had a typo so it pointed to a nonexisting .icns file. In that case you get the same error - so be sure to verify that one too if you run into this issue.